# Arrange long multiple equations with texts between them

Tags: equations, amsmath, multline

I have aligned the equations in the following way but using multiple `\qquad`. I don't think it is a good practice to do so. Moreover the equations should fit within the width of the document. What I really need is something like `\multline` but how do I use it in this case for multiple equations and texts in between them. The equations after the text also should be in the same position as the equations before (I have used `\!` for that in my code). I really don't want to use more packages for this purpose and 'd prefer to stick with `amsmath` or if necessary `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\delta\mathcal{S}(\psi)=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt+\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\dot{\psi}(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left[\frac{d}{dt}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}-\braket{\dot{\psi(t)}|\delta\psi}\right]dt\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}   -i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\dot{\psi}(t)|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&\text{Since } \delta\psi(t_{1})=\delta\psi(t_{2})=0\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\dot{\psi(t)}}^{*}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}^{*}dt
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\braket{\beta|\hat{H}|\alpha}={\braket{\alpha|\hat{H}^{\dagger}|\beta}}^{*}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\!&\quad=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|-{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi}}^{*}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}{\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt\\
\!&\quad=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
\end{article}
```

Comment: In equation environment is forbidden use ampersands (&) . (Tat is reason for errors in compilation of your MWE). Instead ``\begin{equation*}`` you should use for example ``\begin{align*}`` or other asmath environments. For text between equation the ``intertext{....}`` can be handy. Since your system  of equations is terrible mess, I need more time to put them in order and show where and how to use ``interttext{...}``. I will do this at evening if someone else doesn't do before.

Comment: @Zarko i have used `&` in between `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}` to align them and it displays the result when it is compiled. But I want the long equations to be arranged as when we use `\multline` instead of arranging with `&` and using multiple `\qquad`.

Comment: Just a semantic question: what is the `\braket` here for? Is it a justification of the previous line?

Comment: @Bernard `\braket` is used to write the quantum mechanical operator for the expectation value. It is part of the equation. try to compile the code pls. That will be clear.

Comment: Your original MWE gives error which disaper if I replace ``equation*`` with ``align*``. I'm glad to see that meanwhile (during my Sunday lunch with my family :-)) you clean up your MWE and receive two answers, which both gives nice results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `align*` and `multlined` (which requires `mathtools`); for the explanations and keeping the alignment, use `\intertext`.

I provided a better definition of `\braket` that doesn't place the asterisk at random places; use `\braket[*]{x|y}` for having a superscript asterisk. Also a better notation for the differential has been added and an abbreviation for the differential operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,xparse}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!d}
\newcommand{\pdert}{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}
\RenewDocumentCommand\braket{om}{%
  \mathinner{\langle{#2}\rangle\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\delta\mathcal{S}(\psi)=
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t+
    \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|i\pdert|\delta\psi(t)}\diff t\\
    -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}\diff t
  \end{multlined}
\\
&=
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t-
  i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\dot{\psi}(t)}\diff t-
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi}\diff t
\\
&=
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t-
    \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left[\frac{d}{\diff t}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}-
                              \braket{\dot{\psi(t)}|\delta\psi}\right]\diff t\\
    -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}\diff t
  \end{multlined}
\\
&=
  \begin{multlined}[t]
    \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t-
    i\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}
    -i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\dot{\psi}(t)|\delta\psi(t)}\diff t\\
    -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}\diff t
  \end{multlined}
\\
\intertext{Since $\delta\psi(t_{1})=\delta\psi(t_{2})=0$}
&=
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert|\psi(t)}\diff t-
  i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[*]{\delta\psi(t)|\dot{\psi(t)}}\diff t-
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[*]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t
\\
\intertext{Using $\braket{\beta|\hat{H}|\alpha}=\braket[*]{\alpha|\hat{H}^{\dagger}|\beta}$}
&=
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t-
  i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[*]{\delta\psi(t)|-{\pdert|\psi}}\diff t-
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}{\braket[*]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}\diff t
\\
&=
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}\diff t-
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[*]{\delta\psi(t)|i{\pdert-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}\diff t
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since `\qquad` inserts `36mu` of horizontal whitespace, 11 consecutive `\qquad` directives can be written more succinctly as `\mkern396mu`.

Here's a solution that uses a *single* `align*` environment, along with a couple of `\intertext` directives and three `\mkern396mu` instructions. I use `\allowdisplaybreaks` as well, just in case a page break needs to occur. I also suggest replacing all `\frac` directives with `\tfrac`. Finally, the two instances of `\dot{\psi(t)}` should probably be written as `\dot{\psi}(t)`, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\delta\mathcal{S}(\psi)
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt+\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&\mkern396mu-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\dot{\psi}(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left[\tfrac{d}{dt}\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}-\braket{\dot{\psi}(t)|\delta\psi}\right]dt\\
&\mkern396mu-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\braket{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}   -i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\dot{\psi}(t)|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
&\mkern396mu-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
\intertext{Since $\delta\psi(t_{1})= \delta\psi(t_{2})=0$}
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\dot{\psi}(t)}^{*}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}^{*}dt\\
\intertext{And since $\braket{\beta|\hat{H}|\alpha}={\braket{\alpha|\hat{H}^{\dagger}|\beta}}^{*}$}
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|-{\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi}}^{*}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}{\braket{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt\\
&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket{\delta\psi(t)|i{\tfrac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose two different alignments instead of multlined. I also redefined the `\braket` command thanks to `\mathtools` and `xparse` to have a simple syntax, close to what one writes by hand, namely:: `\braket{a|b|c}`.

Also note that, if you use the geometry package (without changing whatever), a number of equations don't have to be split across lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\braketargs{#1}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\braketargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{|}}m }
{\braketargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\braketargsaux}{ m m m}%
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \delta\mathcal{S}(\psi)&=
  \! \begin{aligned}[t]\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt +\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\delta\psi(t)}dt&\\
  -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt&
  \end{aligned}\\
    & = \! \begin{aligned}[t]\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)| i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}| \psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\delta\dot{\psi}(t)}dt & \\-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi}dt &
  \end{aligned}\\
  &= \! \begin{aligned}[t]\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left[\frac{d}{dt}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)}-\braket[\big]{\dot{\psi(t)}|\delta\psi}\right]dt & \\
  \smash[t]{-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt &
  \end{aligned}\\
    & = \! \begin{aligned}[t]\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\delta\psi(t)} -i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\dot{\psi}(t)|\delta\psi(t)}dt & \\ -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt &
  \end{aligned}\\
  \intertext{Since $ \delta\psi(t_{1})=\delta\psi(t_{2})=0 $}
    & = \! \begin{aligned}[t]\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\delta\psi(t)|\dot{\psi(t)}}^{*}dt & \\-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\big]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}^{*}dt &
  \end{aligned}\\
  \braket[\big]{\beta|\hat{H}|\alpha} & \! \begin{aligned}[t]={\braket[\big]{\alpha|\hat{H}^{\dagger}|\beta}}^{*}
  =\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|-{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi}}^{*}dt & \\ -\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}{\braket[\big]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt &
  \end{aligned}\\
  &=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt
\end{align*}
\newpage
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
  \delta\mathcal{S}(\psi) & =
  \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt +\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\delta\psi(t)}dt \\ \MoveEqLeft[-3]-\smash[t]{\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\ \MoveEqLeft[-3]\smash[t]{-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}}\braket[\big]{\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\delta\psi(t)}dt\\
  \intertext{Since $ \delta\psi(t_{1})=\delta\psi(t_{2})=0 $: } \\
  \MoveEqLeft[-3]-\smash[t]{\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}}\braket[\big]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}^{*}dt\\
  \braket[\big]{\beta|\hat{H}|\alpha} & ={\braket[\big]{\alpha|\hat{H}^{\dagger}|\beta}}^{*}
  =\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}dt-i\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\braket[\Big]{\delta\psi(t)|-{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi}}^{*}dt & \\
  \MoveEqLeft[-3]-\smash[t]{\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}}{\braket[\big]{\delta\psi(t)|\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt\\ t}-\hat{H}|\psi(t)}}^{*}dt
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]